# Python LDAP3 Search in multiple search_base at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory, ldap, ldap3

I have a code like this:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection

uri = 'ldaps://ca1.ad.xxx.com:123'
bind_user = 'CN=svc_bind_user,OU=Service Accounts,DC=subdomain1,DC=ad,DC=xxx,DC=com'
bind_password = 'svc_bind_p4$$'

server = Server(uri)
conn = Connection(server, bind_user, bind_password)
conn.bind()

user_filter = 'objectClass=*'
user_name_attr = 'sAMAccountName'
search_scope = 'SUBTREE'
```

I can **successfully** search for `user1` **user1@subdomain1.ad.xxx.com** like this

```
username = 'user1'
search_base= 'DC=subdomain1,DC=ad,DC=xxx,DC=com'
search_filter = "(&({0})({1}={2}))".format(
    user_filter,
    user_name_attr,
    username
)
res = conn.search(search_base,
                  search_filter,
                  search_scope)
```

as well as `user2` **user2@subdomain2.ad.xxx.com** like this

```
username = 'user2'
search_base= 'DC=subdomain2,DC=ad,DC=xxx,DC=com'
search_filter = "(&({0})({1}={2}))".format(
    user_filter,
    user_name_attr,
    username
)
res = conn.search(search_base,
                  search_filter,
                  search_scope)
```

As you can see codes above are tailored for each user to look into different  `search_base` : `subdomain1` and `subdomain2` accordingly

I tired to search for both `user1` and `user2` in a code like this with a higher level `search_base= 'DC=ad,DC=xxx,DC=com'` :

```
username = 'user1'
search_base= 'DC=ad,DC=xxx,DC=com'
search_filter = "(&({0})({1}={2}))".format(
    user_filter,
    user_name_attr,
    username
)
res = conn.search(search_base,
                  search_filter,
                  search_scope)
```

but the code above doesn't find the user, only returns a list of **subdomains**

So the question is, if I am not doing anything wrong here, is there a way to search within multiple domains, by having a perhaps `search_base` with special syntax that combines multiple subdomains?

I don't want to do multiple searches and also as I mentioned the SUBTREE/higher level serach_base does not seem to work for me either

Thanks

Comment: @cannatag help please !

Comment: If your only requirement is to search for user across multiple domains, you can do the same from a single domain by using Global Catalog in AD (default port 3268/3269).

Comment: Worked! Just like that! thanks @Am_I_Helpful

Comment: Please give an answer for future visitors on what you did which helped you resolve the problem! Cheers :).

Comment: @Zac please share your solution

Comment: The problem with global catalog search @Am_I_Helpful suggested is that only limited attributes are returned through it.